# lightbox and "a" attributes (want separate results)

Tags: css, attributes, lightbox

I gather that coming here is like asking Einstein about long-division, but hoping someone can help- I've searched google, and this site, and can't find the answer. I'm sorry if my terminology isn't great- I'm teaching myself this stuff presently.

I've attributes for `a`, `a:link`, `a:hover`, etc, which should apply to text links only. I want to use lightbox but don't want lightbox thumbnails getting the same treatment as text links.

Is there a way to do this? I looked at the lightbox site, and see that links will have a "rel" in them- will this circumvent the attributes I currently have in place, or will my lightbox links also have the border when hovering? If not, how would I create separate attributes for lightbox links?

I would really appreciate any help. I've found answers to pretty much every question I've ever had on this site without actually having to ask, but this one I cannot find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this is adding a class name to your lightbox links and styling for that class specifically.

```
<a href="#" class="lb_link">Lightbox Link</a>

<style>
a.lb_link {
  border: none;
}
</style>
```

What I'm doing with the style is targeting links with the class lb_link and adding specific styles for those.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thank you for the help!